# Adding a LESS Bootstrap mixin to the body with a background image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'm trying to use a background image with the gradient LESS Bootstrap mixin, but it's not working, I've imported all the Bootstrap `.less` files to a `style.less` file, where my `theme.less` is imported (this file). whenever I do the following the grunt task runner, doesn't compile the theme.less file. I have this code:

```
@base-url: '../img/backgrounds';

body {
  background: #gradient.directional(#333; #000; 45deg), url('@{base-url}/bus.jpg'), no-repeat center center fixed; /* fallback */
  background-size: cover;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I also tried:

```
@base-url: '../img/backgrounds';

body {
  #gradient.directional(#333; #000; 45deg), url('@{base-url}/bus.jpg'), no-repeat center center fixed; /* fallback */
  background-size: cover;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

In the second example the compiler says that I have a ')' missing in line 9 column 49

Answer (score 0):

I got it now, all I needed to do it was modify the bootstrap gradients mixin file in "bootstrap/mixins/gradients" folder, I changed the name of the mixin and did my own, with the background image. like this:

mymixins.less file:

```
@base-url: '../img/backgrounds';

#gradient1 {
    .directional1(@start-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1); @end-color: rgba(0,0,0,1); @deg: 45deg) {
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@deg, @start-color, @end-color),url('@{base-url}/bus.jpg'), no-repeat center center fixed;  // Safari 5.1-6, Chrome 10+
        background: -o-linear-gradient(@deg, @start-color, @end-color), url('@{base-url}/bus.jpg'), no-repeat center center fixed; // Opera 12
        background: linear-gradient(@deg, @start-color, @end-color), url('@{base-url}/bus.jpg'), no-repeat center center fixed; // Standard, IE10, Firefox 16+, Opera 12.10+, Safari 7+, Chrome 26+
    }
}
```

my theme.less file:

```
.background {
    #gradient1.directional1(rgba(255,255,255,0.3); rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 45deg);
    background-size: cover;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Assuming you want the `no-repeat center center fixed` to apply to the `url('@{base-url}/bus.jpg')`, there shouldn't be a comma separating them. Commas are used to define multiple backgrounds (as in the comma between your gradient background and your image background)